# React native grid like instagram

Tags: css, react-native, gridview

How can we achieve the grid like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IxNT.png). I looked in many react native libraries but still in search of it. I tried a custom grid view but creating an issue when not having more data.
Please let me know the best way for it.

Comment: Why you are not using FlatList and design one for your self? Do you want the same size grids? I will make one for you.

Comment: Yes I tried but not able to set such grid see  I tried . https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyks4.png
If you can make, please make  :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to do it for my project By creating a custom component.

**Note:** Before you use the following component keep in mind that:

1. I have used `ScrollView` instead of `FlatList` because it wasn't feasible in my case. And it might not be that efficient.
2. I have used external library `lodash` Please make sure to install that.
3. This is only working with 3 Column images but you can make changes according to your need.
4. I have a custom sub-component called `MyImage` which handles loading and errors according to my need. You can skip and use your Image tag or Any Other.

**Explanation:**

I created cells containing three images. There are a total of 3 types of cells.

1. Big Image on the right side.
2. Big Image on the left side.
3. Normal grid with No Big Image.

I create chunks or we can array of arrays using `lodash` which works as data for each row. Each small chunk or array will have 3 objects.

`groupEveryNthRow = 3` means I'll have cell with a big image on every 3rd row starting from 0.

`bigImageSide` represents that on which side the big image should appear. I keep changing left to right. You can choose according to your case.

All other code is just self-explanatory. Let me know if you don't understand anything else.

**Code**

`InstaGrid.js`

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Dimensions,
  ScrollView,
  ActivityIndicator,
} from 'react-native';
var {width} = Dimensions.get('window');
import * as _ from 'lodash';
import MyImage from './MyImage';

const InstaGrid = ({
  data,
  columns,
  onEndReachedThreshold,
  onEndReached,
  loading = false,
  onItemClick,
}) => {
  const groupEveryNthRow = 3;
  const {mainContainer, groupedGridContainer} = styles;
  var currentRow = 0;
  const rowsArray = _.chunk(data, columns);
  var bigImageSide = 'right';

  const renderGroupedItem = (row) => {
    const smallImage1 = row[0];
    const smallImage2 = row[1];
    const largeImage = row[2];

    if (bigImageSide === 'right') {
      bigImageSide = 'left';
      return (
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
          <View style={groupedGridContainer}>
            <View style={styles.gridStyle}>
              <MyImage
                style={styles.imageThumbnail}
                sourceObj={smallImage1}
                onPress={() => {
                  onItemClick(smallImage1);
                }}
              />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.gridStyle}>
              <MyImage
                style={styles.imageThumbnail}
                sourceObj={smallImage2}
                onPress={() => {
                  onItemClick(smallImage2);
                }}
              />
            </View>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.gridStyle}>
            <MyImage
              style={styles.imageThumbnailLarge}
              sourceObj={largeImage}
              onPress={() => {
                onItemClick(largeImage);
              }}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      );
    } else {
      bigImageSide = 'right';
      return (
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
          <View style={styles.gridStyle}>
            <MyImage
              style={styles.imageThumbnailLarge}
              sourceObj={largeImage}
              onPress={() => {
                onItemClick(largeImage);
              }}
            />
          </View>
          <View style={groupedGridContainer}>
            <View style={styles.gridStyle}>
              <MyImage
                style={styles.imageThumbnail}
                sourceObj={smallImage1}
                onPress={() => {
                  onItemClick(smallImage1);
                }}
              />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.gridStyle}>
              <MyImage
                style={styles.imageThumbnail}
                sourceObj={smallImage2}
                onPress={() => {
                  onItemClick(smallImage2);
                }}
              />
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      );
    }
  };

  const renderSingleItem = (item) => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.gridStyle}>
        <MyImage
          style={styles.imageThumbnail}
          sourceObj={item}
          onPress={() => {
            onItemClick(item);
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  };

  const renderCell = (row) => {
    if (row.length >= columns && currentRow % groupEveryNthRow === 0) {
      currentRow++;
      return <View>{renderGroupedItem(row)}</View>;
    }
    currentRow++;
    return (
      <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
        {row.map((item) => {
          return renderSingleItem(item);
        })}
      </View>
    );
  };

  const isCloseToBottom = ({layoutMeasurement, contentOffset, contentSize}) => {
    const paddingToBottom = 20;
    return (
      layoutMeasurement.height + contentOffset.y >=
      contentSize.height - paddingToBottom
    );
  };

  const renderFooter = () => {
    return (
      <View style={{marginBottom: 16}}>
        <ActivityIndicator animating size="large" />
      </View>
    );
  };

  return (
    <ScrollView
      scrollEventThrottle={onEndReachedThreshold}
      onScroll={({nativeEvent}) => {
        if (isCloseToBottom(nativeEvent)) {
          onEndReached();
        }
      }}>
      <View style={mainContainer}>
        {rowsArray.map((row) => {
          return renderCell(row);
        })}
      </View>
      {loading && renderFooter()}
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mainContainer: {
    width: '100%',
  },
  groupedGridContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'column',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  imageThumbnail: {
    height: width / 3 - 12,
    width: width / 3 - 12,
    resizeMode: 'stretch',
    alignSelf: 'flex-start',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
  },
  imageThumbnailLarge: {
    height: width * 0.6 + 12,
    width: width * 0.6 + 12,
    marginLeft: 4,
    resizeMode: 'stretch',
    alignSelf: 'flex-start',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
  },
  gridStyle: {
    margin: 4,
  },
});

export default InstaGrid;
```

`MyImage.js`

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
  ActivityIndicator,
} from 'react-native';

const MyImage = ({style, sourceObj, onPress}) => {
  const [imageError, setImageError] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
      {imageError || !sourceObj.card_images ? (
        <Image
          source={require('../images/userImage.jpg')}
          style={style}
          onLoadEnd={() => setLoading(false)}
        />
      ) : (
        <Image
          style={style}
          source={{uri: sourceObj.card_images.front_image}}
          onError={(e) => {
            setLoading(false);
            setImageError(true);
          }}
          onLoadEnd={() => setLoading(false)}
        />
      )}
      {loading && (
        <ActivityIndicator
          style={styles.activityIndicator}
          animating={loading}
        />
      )}
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  activityIndicator: {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
  },
});

export default MyImage;
```

**How to Use:** Just

```js
<InstaGrid
        data={details}
        columns={3}
        loading={loading}
        onItemClick={(item) => {
          console.log('Got the Item:' + JSON.stringify(item));
        }}
        onEndReachedThreshold={400}
        onEndReached={() => (offset !== -1 ? fetchData() : null)}
      />
```