# implement Instagram like flatlist(grid) in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

I have a simple **Flatlist** with 3 columns and now I need to make some of the **tiles** **larger** than the others, exactly like Instagram **explore** page. does Flatlist support this kind of layout?
big tiles on left or right side of the flatlist rows, and two simple rows in between

how can I make it?
[image: changes i need]

Comment: i found a suggestion to implement this feature but I need to know if there is a simpler or another way to do this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63774370/react-native-grid-like-instagram

Comment: my first code is here but it has low performance and I'm working on it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68622507/react-native-flatlist-is-slow-with-dynamic-items-and-a-big-data